# Comparing timestamps in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp

I am attempting to store a JSON AJAX response from the server in browser `localStorage` for one minute, adding a timestamp via `new Date().getMinutes()`.

On `$(document).ready` I try to compare the timestamp in localStorage with the current timestamp I've set in a variable like this: `new Date().getMinutes().toString()`, if the current timestamp is greater than the one in localStorage then I make the AJAX call again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cache"));

    if (object) { 
        var dateString = object.timestamp,
            now = new Date().getMinutes().toString();

            console.log('cache present. ' + object.timestamp + '  - checking against: ' + now + '');

        if (now > dateString ) { 


            console.log('cache expired - refetching');

            $.getJSON('cart/get', function(data) { 
                var object = {url: 'cart/get', response : data, timestamp: new Date().getMinutes()}
                localStorage.setItem("cache", JSON.stringify(object));
            });

        }

        return object.response;

    } else { 

        console.log('cache not present - set it');

        $.getJSON('cart/get', function(data) {
            var object = {url: 'cart/get', response : data, timestamp: new Date().getMinutes()}
            localStorage.setItem("cache", JSON.stringify(object));
        });

    }                    

});
```

This works, but if the user loads a page at 8:26:57 then reloads it at 8:27:06 the AJAX request will be made even though one minute hasn't elapsed.

My question is: How can I set an exact timestamp in localStorage and compare that with `new Date().getMinutes().toString()` and only make the AJAX request if at least 60 seconds have elapsed?

Comment: well than you need to account for seconds.... and probably milliseconds, so use getTime() and store that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#Measuring_execution_time

Comment: localStorage can only store strings.  So I would advise storing the time in milliseconds (`Date.now()`) as a string, and then when you get it out you can parse it and stick it back in a Date object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the .getTime() result into your localstore, and then, compare it with your current date.getTime(), it will give you the result in milliseconds, so you have to divide it by 1000.

Comment: This helped, thanks. I ended up using `now - dateString > 1*60*1000` in combination with `getTime()`, which I initially misunderstood.

Comment: You're welcome. With that logic it would evaluate if has passed an hour, it looks well.